# WebClient on WP7 does not download the entire string, instead cuts it off arbitrarily

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, rest, webclient

I am trying to download a long string of JSON from a public API on Windows Phone 7, but am finding that the whole JSON is not being downloaded, the string is cut off at different lengths depending on the file chosen. I've tried this using both `OpenReadAsync` and `DownloadStringAsync`.

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.DownloadStringComplteted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(DownloadStringCompleted);
wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://api.example.com"));
```

By inserting a breakpoint just inside the event completed handler I can see that the `args.Result` property does not contain the full string of the API and is cut off at different intervals.

This same procedure works elsewhere in the app, I've tested the API and ensured that `content-length` is correct and all that - I still cannot work out why the string is getting cut off by the WebClient.

Comment: How do you know it's being cut off? I know I used to print my output of a webrequest to the console, but for a very long string it never managed to print it entirely and just cut it off as well. Perhaps this is the same?

Comment: I added breakpoints to inspect both the `args.Result` as well as a `.ToString()` variant of the result inside the inspector. It shows a considerable portion of the result which is then seemingly cut off. Furthermore, JSON.NET fails to parse the JSON following which I attribute to the JSON being incomplete, so it isn't just the inspector not showing the complete result.